# SQL: Select Query with Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data as below:

[image]

From that table I want to get output like:

[image]

Actual requirements is to show `Entity` with both `IsDefault` and `IsOwner` as `"Y"`.

If no data with that condition, then the next condition is select `Entity` with `IsDefault` is `"Y"`.

If no, then select `Entity` with `IsOwner` is `"Y"`.

If no `Entity` with value `"Y"`, that `Entity` will not be shown.

Each `Entity` shown atleast once.

I tried with below query:

> SELECT ENTITY_ID,IS_DEFAULT,IS_OWNER FROM #TEMP_CHART WHERE (IS_DEFAULT='Y' OR IS_OWNER ='Y')

But showing same `Entity` two times as below:

[image]

Is there any select query to get above output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rank()` window function to get the data as require:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over (
            partition by entity order by isDefault desc,
                IsOwner desc
            ) rn
    from your_table t
    where isDefault = 'Y'
        or IsOwner = 'Y'
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

The ordering in the window function is very important here.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/SEO69076)

Answer (score 1):

You can give a rank by `DENSE_RANK` based on the `IsDefault` and `IsOwner` columns.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = dense_rank() over(
        partition by [Entity]
        order by 
          case [IsDefault] when 'Y' then 1
          else 2 end,
          case [IsOwner] when 'Y' then 1
          else 2 end
    ), * 
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [Entity], [IsDefault], [IsOwner]  from cte
where [rn] = 1;
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/637953/select-query-with-conditions)**

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSGe2.png)

try to execute above code.. you will get the result..

Comment: You should avoid linking to answer, if You could put answer in text format right on SO page.